# move a gameobject position in a slow motion unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanna move the Camera (GameObject) to be like navigating between panels... Its working well but I want it to be in a slow motion to be like animation. I am using unity and c#.
Thank you for your help

```
public class moveCanvas : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 reset = new Vector3(0, 0, -10);
    Vector3 leftpanel = new Vector3(-205.5f, 0, 0);
    Vector3 rightpanel = new Vector3(205.5f, 0, 0);


    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            GoLeft();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            GoRight();
        }

    }

    public void GoLeft()
    {
        Vector3 currentposition = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.position;
        if (currentposition == reset)
            GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.position = leftpanel;
        else if (currentposition == rightpanel)
            GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.position = reset;
        else
            return;

    }

    public void GoRight()
    {
        Vector3 currentposition = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.position;
        if (currentposition == reset)
              GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.position = rightpanel;
        else if (currentposition == leftpanel)
            GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.position = reset;
        else
          return; 

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked lerp or slerp? Also there are tweens like [itween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/). With those you can make the transaction animations you like

Comment: Make your camera move, instead of jump to the new position.

Comment: You don't need to do `else return` in a `void` function. The only time you need to do that is if you're returning a value, like `else return 5;`. The computer will return from the function, that's why there is no compile error when you don't have it. Also, you might as well put it all on one line, anyways

Comment: I tried lerp and slerp and It didnt work...Thank you but I didnt get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the answer

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveCanvas : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 _reset = new Vector3(0, 0, -10);
    private Vector3 _leftpanel = new Vector3(-205.5f, 0, 0);
    private Vector3 _rightpanel = new Vector3(205.5f, 0, 0);
    private float _smoothTime = 0.7f;
    private Vector3 _velocity = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 _currentposition;
    private int _stoplimit = 2;

    void Start()
    {
        _currentposition = gameObject.transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            StartCoroutine(GoLeft());
        }

        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            StartCoroutine(GoRight());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator GoLeft()
    {
        if (_currentposition == _reset)
        {
            while (!Mathf.Approximately(_currentposition.x, _leftpanel.x))
            {
                gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(_currentposition, _leftpanel, ref _velocity, _smoothTime);
                _currentposition = gameObject.transform.position;
                if (Mathf.Abs((_currentposition.x) - (_leftpanel.x)) < _stoplimit)
                {
                    break;
                }
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
            gameObject.transform.position = _leftpanel;
            _currentposition = _leftpanel;

        }

        else if (_currentposition == _rightpanel)
        {
            while (!Mathf.Approximately(_currentposition.x, _reset.x))
            {
                gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(_currentposition, _reset, ref _velocity, _smoothTime);
                _currentposition = gameObject.transform.position;
                if (Mathf.Abs((_currentposition.x) - (_reset.x)) < _stoplimit)
                {
                    break;
                }
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
            gameObject.transform.position = _reset;
            _currentposition = _reset;

        }
    }

    private IEnumerator GoRight()
    {
        if (_currentposition == _reset)
        {
            while (!Mathf.Approximately(_currentposition.x, _rightpanel.x))
            {
                gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(_currentposition, _rightpanel, ref _velocity, _smoothTime);
                _currentposition = gameObject.transform.position;
                if (Mathf.Abs((_currentposition.x) - (_rightpanel.x)) < _stoplimit)
                {
                    break;
                }
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
            gameObject.transform.position = _rightpanel;
            _currentposition = _rightpanel;

        }
        else if (_currentposition == _leftpanel)
        {
            while (!Mathf.Approximately(_currentposition.x, _reset.x))
            {
                gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(_currentposition, _reset, ref _velocity, _smoothTime);
                _currentposition = gameObject.transform.position;
                if (Mathf.Abs((_currentposition.x) - (_reset.x)) < _stoplimit)
                {
                    break;
                }
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
            gameObject.transform.position = _reset;
            _currentposition = _reset;


        }
    }

}
```